# Academic Positions: Following a campus visit, when are referees contacted?

Tags: interview

I`ve had my phone interview followed by a campus visit for a tenure faculty position. I was wondering if anyone has an experience as for when references are usually contacted?. This is in reference to universities in the U.S.
Thanks,

Comment: My (top 5 CS) department automatically contacts referees for _all_ assistant professor applicants as soon as they apply. But practices vary significantly by field. What's yours?

Comment: I have recently been offered a more or less equivalent position to assistant professor ("lecturer") in the UK. My references were contacted *after* they unofficially made me the offer. The official offer will be made after positive reference letters have been provided.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, with universities that are often considered to be among the top 50 institutions in North America, *referees will be contacted prior to a campus visit*. Often times the decision to invite someone for a campus visit is expensive - time and $$$ - and universities/departments use as much information as they can get beforehand to decide on inviting a candidate for a visit.

Comment: Thanks. I agree. They really spent a lot of money on my visit and this is one of the best programs in my field in the U.S. I`m going to follow up with my references to know if they have been contacted. But at the same time some departments contact the references only after the campus visit. I also heard that some universities contact references after they made the offer.

Comment: Are you not being reimbursed for the cost of your visit?

Comment: @Change, most places will obtain references ahead of time when they are recruiting for a starting position (Assistant Professor, for example). When recruiting a more senior candidate for, say, a full professor position there may be some reasons to delay the reference request.

Comment: @Thomas. I didn't pay anything. The University made the flight reservation, hotel, meals, car and trip insurance and car insurance. Any other expenses that came up, they will reimburse. I still didn't send the receipts for the small amounts because they paid a lot of money already.